# Haskell Syntax: Parse Error On Input

Tags: haskell, syntax-error

As part of a mini-haskell compiler that I'm writing, I have a function named `app`. What I want this function to do is take in these arguments `epp (App e1 e2)`. The first step would be to evaluate `e1` recursively (`epp e1`) and check if the output would be an error. If not then evaluate `e2` and then call another function `eppVals` to evaluate the outputs of the calls on `e1` and `e2` which I defined as `v1` and `v2` respectively.

Comment: I expect that it is a matter of indentation. Hunt and remove all tabs in your source file. If the two bindings for `v1` and `v2` line up with pure spaces, it ought to parse.

Comment: @DanielFischer i did that and now i get an `parse error on input v2`

Comment: Can you paste the _exact_ source here? Copy from your file, paste, select, Ctrl+K to indent as code. If the two `v`s are in the same column, it must parse.

Comment: @DanielFischer check above. the two `v`s do line up

Comment: Today I learned about Ctrl+K.

Comment: Copied, pasted, filled up with a few dummy definitions: parses and compiles. If it doesn't parse for you, there must be something else wrong with your file. Can you paste it somewhere (http://hpaste.org for example) in its entirety?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your hpaste you have a function `appVals` which has been renamed to `eppVals` in your question above. This is unhelpful.

Let's look at some types:

- `epp :: Exp -> Error Val`
- `appVals :: Val -> Val -> Error Val`

The error message *Couldn't match expected type `Val` with actual type `Error Val`* is trying to tell you that the first parameter to `appVals` is *expected* to have type `Val` (see type signature for `appVals`) but the *actual type* of the value you've provided as the first parameter is `v1`, defined as `epp e1`, which has type `Error Val` (see type signature for `epp`).

`Val` and `Error Val` are not the same type. That's your problem.

How to fix it? You need some way of handling the error cases separately from the rest of the computation. If you have implemented the `Applicative` or `Monad` classes for your `Error` type, this is almost certainly what they do.

**Edit:** You don't include the definition of your `Error`, but I expect it looks like this:

```
data Error a = S a | Error String
```

Implement a couple of classes for it (you'll need to `import Control.Applicative`):

```
instance Functor Error where
    fmap f (S x)     = S (f x)
    fmap _ (Error s) = Error s

instance Applicative Error where
    pure = S
    Error s <*> _       = Error s
    _       <*> Error s = Error s
    S f     <*> S x     = S (f x)
```

Now you can rewrite

```
epp (App e1 e2) = eppVals <$> epp e1 <*> epp e2
```