# Haskell Switch/Case Use

Tags: haskell, recursion, switch-statement

As part of a mini interpreter that I'm writing in Haskell, I'm writing a function that does the following: In case of `eval (App e1 e2)`, I want to recursively evaluate `e1` (`eval e1`), setting the result to `v1`. Then using Switch/Case, I want to check the pattern of the `v1` and if it's not an Error then recursively evaluate `e2` (`eval e2`) and setting that value to `v2`. Using these two values `v1` and `v2`, then I apply another function (`appVals`) on those values.

```
eval :: Exp -> Error Val
eval (App e1 e2) = appVals v1 v2 where
    v1 = case (eval e1) of
        Error err -> Error "Not an application"
        /= Error err -> eval e1 = v1
    v2 = case (eval e2) of
        Error err -> Error "Not an application"
        /= Error err -> eval e2 = v2
```

I think I may have figured it out but I'm not entirely sure I've done the switch/case part correctly. Any ideas/suggests?

Comment: FYI, this (creating a "mini-language") is a good thing to make use of GADTs for -- http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/GADT

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The second part of your case statement shouldn't try to retest because you already know it's not an `Error` - that would have matched the first. (Skip `/= Error err`.)

`eval e1 = v1` tries to redo the eval you did at the start. You don't need to do that.

Here's what I think you intended to do:

```
eval :: Exp -> Error Val
eval (App e1 e2) = case eval e1 of
    Error _ -> Error "Not an application"
    S v1    ->    case eval e2 of        -- nested case statement
     Error _ -> Error "Not an application"
     S v2    -> appVals v1 v2            -- match the S away
```

But it all seems a bit ugly, so let's take exellent advice from Gabriel Gonzalez and make an applicative out of `Error`.

```
instance Functor Error where
   fmap f (Error e) = Error e  -- pass through errors
   fmap f (S x)     = S (f x)  -- edit successes
```

So for example, `fmap (+4) (Error "oops") = Error "oops"` whereas `fmap (+4) (S 5) = S 9`.

If this `fmap` is all new to you, why not read a [Functors tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13134825/how-do-functors-work-in-haskell/13137359#13137359)?

Next let's make an Applicative instance. Applicative lets you use complicated functions like simple ones.
You need to `import Control.Applicative` at the top of your file to get it working.

```
instance Applicative Error where
    pure x = S x   -- how to put ordinary data in
    S f     <*> S x     = S (f x)
    Error e <*> _       = Error e
    _       <*> Error e = Error e
```

Now, if there weren't any errors then you'd define

```
appVal' :: Val -> Val -> Val

eval' :: Exp -> Val
eval' (App e1 e2) = appVal' (eval' e1) (eval' e2)
```

With applicative, we can use `<$>` which works a bit like `$` except it does whatever plumbing you defined in `fmap`.
Similarly, `<*>` works a bit like  function application, except for the extra plumbing, so we can define

```
eval :: Exp -> Error Val
eval (App e1 e2) = appVals <$> eval e1 <*> eval e2
```

which is a nice clean way of dealing with the errors behind the scenes whilst focussing on the functionality.

Comment: i added some other information for you to check out above. does that help any?

Comment: @NuNu Yes. Thanks. I've reanswered.

Answer (score 4):

[I left you yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13426449/haskell-syntax-parse-error-on-input/13429870#13429870) (modulo renaming) with

```
eval (App e1 e2) = appVals <$> eval e1 <*> eval e2
```

This is almost what you want, the difference being that if either of the two inputs is an error, you want to replace it with a specific error message. (What I don't understand is why.) So let's write a function to do just that last bit!

```
butError :: String -> Error a -> Error a
butError message (Error _) = Error message
butError _       noError   = noError
```

Now you can rewrite your `eval` clause as

```
eval (App e1 e2) = appVals <$> butError message (eval e1) <*> butError message (eval e2)
  where message = "Not an application"
```

Answer (score 3):

I assume that you have some data type that looks like:

```
data Result a = Error String | Success a
```

The solution to your problem is to either:

(a) Make your `Result` type a `Monad`

(b) Use `Either String` instead of result, since it already has a `Monad` instance.

Whichever you do, then you would just write:

```
eval :: SyntaxTree a -> Result a
eval (App ef ex) = do
    f <- eval ef
    x <- eval ex
    return (f x)
```

Technically, an `Applicative` suffices for this purpose, and you could instead write:

```
eval (App ef ex) = eval ef <*> eval ex
```

Answer (score 2):

In a `case`, you need to have *patterns* for the alternatives, you can't have an `/= Error err` there.

Also, you cannot have a `=` on the right of an arrow `->` in a `case` expression, so `-> eval e1 = v1` is not valid Haskell.

In your case, you only care that it is not an `Error something`, but once the first pattern has not matched, that is automatically the case, and since you don't care what else you get, you can use a variable pattern:

```
eval (App e1 e2) = appVals v1 v2 where
    v1 = case (eval e1) of
        Error err -> Error "Not an application"
        other -> other
    v2 = case (eval e2) of
        Error err -> Error "Not an application"
        other -> other
```